# Records in collection not logged

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

[image]

Trying out nodejs with mongodb.
Not sure why my data is not logged in terminal , i am getting an empty array.I am a beginer in backend development.

Comment: You can try providing a database name in the statement `client.db()` method.

Comment: no luck , i was following along a course the intstructor had used mongodb via docker i tried using atlas while using docker i was getting the result but not with mongodb atlas